# How to revoke specific (or all) user permissions in Android for Facebook Login SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the latest version of Facebook SDK (May 2015). How can I programatically revoke/remove a user's specific permission (or all) after the user has logged in via Facebook Login SDK in an Android Application? I found the following in the developer documentation, but I am not sure how to programatically do this. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution on how to Revoke a User's Permission in the latest version of Facebook Android SDK (Graph API 2.0+ and above). This is per May 2015. The developer needs to use **GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest()** and set the **GraphPath** and set the **HttpMethod** to DELETE.

```
public void graphRevokeUserStatusPermission(){
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if(accessToken == null)
            return;

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/me/permissions/user_status",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        // response
                    }
                }
        );
        request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

and if you want to revoke user access just change graph path to

```
    String userId = accessToken.getUserId();
    //url to revoke login DELETE {user_id}/permissions
    userId + "permissions"
```

and don't forget to clear info in onCompleted method calling [LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/#logOut), this logout method doesn't revoke access, it just clear token and profile info, so developer needs to request url to revoke access

More info:

[Facebook Permissions Revoking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#revoking)

Comment: i noticed this answer now, yes you are right this is how you revoke it, Congrats.

Comment: @Jhonatas (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8282660)): You probably should post that as a separate answer.

Comment: it does work perfect. in my case I use the graphPath  "/me/permissions" then delete all, next time whne the user login it ask for permission all again. it is uselful for testing.  thank for you answer

Answer (score 4):

Revoking permissions is easy now with the new 4.x.x versions of Facebook Sdk for Android

For read permissions

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(fragmentoractivity, Arrays.asList("user_likes"));
//multiple
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(fragmentoractivity, Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_friends"));
```

For publish permissions

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(fragmentoractivity, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

The delete or revoking is not necessary, just ask for permissions like this whenever you want to revoke them

for example if the user has denied the permission, then also you can simply use the above commands to ask for the permission again.

### Note: you must comply with facebook policies, example you must prompt the user before asking fr permissions or ask for permission when user clicks a action which needs a permission to access.

Update:

If you want to delete permission then execute a graph request with method delete

```
String graphPath="/me/permissions/user_likes";
GraphRequest deletepermission=new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), graphPath, null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        if(graphResponse!=null){
                            FacebookRequestError error =graphResponse.getError();
                            if(error!=null){
                                Log.e(ERRORTAG, error.toString());
                            }else {
                                //permission deleted or revoked
                            }
                        }
                      }         
                    });
deletepermission.executeAsync();
//or
deletepermission.executeAndWait()
```

above two commands or similar commands can be used to execute graph requests
if you have multiple requests then use GraphRequestBatch (check fb documentation)

Now all you need to edit is the String graphPath, you can replace the "user_likes" with permission you want to revoke or you can remove this part to revoke all permissions at once.

Also make sure the HttpMethod.DELETE is required to delete.

Comment: Thank you dijeet. I will try this. Also, if I am creating a sample development app that is not going to be released to play store, is it necessary for me to Submit for Review Approval to be able to use all extended permissions? I would like to use all just for testing.

Comment: As long as all of the users are listed in your Facebook developer console as an admin, developer, or tester of the app, you do not need login review in order to use the permissions.

Comment: @user3268305   Thanks for the answer , how can I set a user to admin, developer, or tester of the app through FB Developer Console?  I'd like to enable every permission for the purpose of testing

Comment: developers.facebook.com -> My Apps -> <your app> -> Roles

Comment: Hi @Diljeet . I tried to call the same API as you mentioned above to "revoke", but it seems to only enable the permission. It doesn't seem to "toggle" the permission ON/OFF as I expect. Do you know how to "delete" the permission tied to the user?

Comment: @android-user I updated the answer to delete permission, also please read all permission related articles as i have faced a lot of issues integrating the facebook sdk recently to my app.